# Draw fast in Android

Tags: android

I'm developing an app for Android (API level 11), that reads some data from a device, one chunk a second. I want to plot the data, x-axis being time in seconds and y-axis being the values. One of the requirements for the program is that I must show the results of one hour of observations on one screen without any scrolling, so I must fit 3600 points on the screen. It doesn't matter that the points overlap.

I don't know how to plot the data fast enough.

I'm using androidplot, and things get really slow in approximately 30 minutes, as androidplot redraws the same points over and over again.

I tried to make some changes to it (as the sources can be freely downloaded), but in vain.

Can I somehow cache the previously drawn image and add only new points to it?

Is there something like WinAPI BitBlt() function in Android?

Comment: Its impossible to do that since you don't have enough pixels on a phone screen to render 3600 data points, you would have overlapping data points.